# The Second Conditional

Tags: sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions

> If I saw him yesterday, I'd talk to him.

How should I understand the meaning of this sentence? As I understand this meaning should refer to unreal situation.

Comment: In essence it means *Had I seen him yesterday, I would have spoken to him*. But I believe it is using the incorrect verb forms in order to achieve a sense of irony to mark something ridiculous - perhaps because the speaker is referring to a character from history, such as William the Conqueror.

Comment: As written, it makes no sense. The second conditional is used for unreal present situations. You can't use a finished time expression if you want to state a hypothetical situation in the present.

Comment: It's grammatical, it just requires some mental olympics to come up with a context where it makes sense.  Speaking of which, what was the context you found this sentence in?

Comment: Adding back the implied *then* makes this a bit clearer:  > If I saw him yesterday [then] I would talk to him.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, your sentence means

> **If I saw him yesterday, I'd talk to him.**
>   If I saw him yesterday, I would talk to him *(today)*

says that you would talk to him **now**, conditioned on seeing him the day before.
However, the construction is **awkward**.

> If I **had seen** him yesterday, I **would have spoken** to him

might be better with the meaning that yesterday, you did not **see** him and did not **talk** to him, but you would have done both if you **saw** him. **would have** is conditional on **seen**

Answer (score 0):

In essence it means *Had I seen him yesterday, I would have spoken to him*.

But I believe it is using the incorrect verb forms in order to achieve a sense of irony, in order to mark something which is ridiculous - perhaps because the speaker is referring to a character from history, such as Julius Caesar, or William the Conqueror.

Answer (score -1):

It is a unreal situation. In this one is saying that if he had  seen him yesterday he would surely had talked to him.